# Relational Query and their behaviour

Tags: parse-platform

I'm a newbie at parse and I love it, but so far, I've had a couple of issues when making Relational queries. Here's some background:

- I have the default user object. One of their columns is a pointer to
  an object called Careers, which contains a list of posible
  universities a user can attend. This column stores the objectID of
  that career.

This is my code:

```
var userId //I got the user id from Parse.User.Current()
var uObj = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var uObjQuery = new Parse.Query(uObj);
uObjQuery.equalTo("objectId", userId);
uObjQuery.include("Career");
uObjQuery.first({
  success: function(object) {
    console.log(object);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

When I see the results, I get something like this:

```
{
"Career": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Careers",
    "objectId": "YicXSU65Qn"
},
"email": "The user mail",
"first_name": "The user first name",
"last_name": "The user last name",
"profilePicture": "a url",
"username": "The username",
"objectId": "The user objectId",
"createdAt": "2015-01-19T08:46:35.205Z",
"updatedAt": "2015-01-19T10:42:53.098Z"
}
```

which kinda makes sense, but I was expecting to get something like a join, so I could use the attributes of Career object.

Does this mean I have to make a second query to Career's object using the data I just got?

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I've corrected the typo of `uObjQuery.include("Career");`.

**Edit2:** This is the data from Career object I should be able to see
[image: Career Attrs]

Answer (score 1):

You have a type mistake. Your table name is **Career**, not **Careers**. Also, the name you are going to use in the `include` method is the name of the column, not the name of the table.

And use `new Parse.Query(Parse.User);` instead.

https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-relational is always helpful.

Comment: Yes, that is a typo, but because I translated it to english for a better understanding. My code indeed includes
`uObjQuery.include("Career");`

Is is possible that I've unproperly designed the column?

Comment: So, go back to your User and check whether the column name of that pointer is "Career". I don't think there are anything problems in your code.

Comment: Does this mean I have to make a second query to get all Career's object propierties using the data I just got?

Comment: No, make sure the you passed in the column name in the include method. And I don't see any errors of you code. And I think you should get the info from Career table. Or is it because there are no extra data fields in Career table? lol

Comment: Updated! I have a lot more attributes on that object besides the ones on the screenshot and it just won't get them. Could this be a bug?

Comment: I've done all you said, but I'm still getting just the object with only the id. `"Career": {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Careers",
    "objectId": "YicXSU65Qn"
}`  have you tried it succesfully? You know... to get more data from the related content?  Thanks a lot for answering btw.